# Graph theory 27 cube cheese and mouse problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A cubic cheese consists of 27 smaller cubes of cheeses (3x3x3). A mouse will eat the first cheese cube and then eat an adjacent cheese cube (no diagonal eating allowed). Show that the mouse can't end up eating the middle cheese cube last.

**EDIT:**

The mouse has to eat every cube and can't move into empty space.

Any ideas on how to show this?

Comment: Does the mouse have to eat every cube? Can it move into an empty space?

Comment: It does have to eat every cube and it can't move into an empty space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can color your cheese cubes with two colors such that no two adjacent cubes have the same color. Knowing the color of the first cube, what is the color of the last cube the mouse will eat ? And what is the color of the central cube ?